# Add Git security exception fails

Tags: windows, git, nas, shared-folders

I have a windows box where I check out a Github repository.
Then I make a change and commit that change and then get weird error message about a user mismatch related to file ownership:

```
git clone https://github.com/XYZ/repo
git add *
git commit -m "make a change"
git push
```

Error Message:

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//mynas/myuser/project'
'//mynas/myuser/project' is owned by:
'S-1-0-0'
but the current user is:
'S-1-5-21-1666234352-720225400-1659653562-1007'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///mynas/myuser/project'
```

Now for one thing I the `%(prefix)` part looks a bit like a bug of git with a template element that was not populated.

I did try to create the exception as suggested with no success:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///mynas/myuser/project'
git config --global --add safe.directory '///mynas/myuser/project'
```

I even tried a wildcard:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

I did some research and found suggestions to remove the ownerships of given directory as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978485/git-submodule-update-failed-with-fatal-detected-dubious-ownership-in-repositor:

I did try the following too but I am not sure how this works on a shared drive:

```
takeown.exe /f //mynas/myuser/project /r /d y
```

Also this did not work.

Comment: It may not be possible to add a safe directory on a file share, because Git for Windows is not fully native. In any case, you should try the path as displayed on the first line, with two forward slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure the problem.
When adding an exception it is crucial to use double quotes `"*"` instead of single quotes `'*'`

```
git config --global --add safe.directory "*"
```

So after running the command above I could finally check in my files.

I did found the helping comment in the thread I mentioned above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73100228/784318